# How to retrieve data from BLOB?

Tags: javascript, blob

I have created a **BLOB** like this.

```js
var blob = new Blob(["Hello", "World!"]);
blob.slice(0); //=> Blob(11) {size: 11, type: ""}
```

And I don't found any easy way retrieve data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use file reader to extract data from blob, for example

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello", "World!"]);

const buffer = await new Promise(resolve => {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.addEventListener("loadend", () => resolve(fileReader.result));
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
})
```

Comment: Is this the only way todo this?

Comment: @TypeError well, there are other ways also, what exactly are you tying to accomplish

Comment: @TypeError you could fetch the blob as a readable stream and consume it, refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#Consuming_a_fetch_as_a_stream